# How to fix the VHDL error "type of identifier xxx does not agree with its usage as xxx type"?

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to VHDL. My code now looks like this:

...

```
entity g14_lpm is
port ( i_clk    : in std_logic;
        i_rstb  : in std_logic;
         i_x     : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         i_y     : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
         o_xx, o_yy : out std_logic_vector(64 downto 0)
);
end g14_lpm;

architecture arc of g14_lpm is
signal r_x : signed(31 downto 0);
signal r_y : signed(31 downto 0);
signal xx  : signed(63 downto 0);
signal yy  : signed(63 downto 0);
signal xy  : signed(53 downto 0);
component LPM_MULT
```

...

```
port ( DATAA : in std_logic_vector(LPM_WIDTHA-1 downto 0);
         DATAB : in std_logic_vector(LPM_WIDTHB-1 downto 0);
         ACLR  : in std_logic := '0';
         CLOCK : in std_logic := '0';
         CLKEN : in std_logic := '1';
         RESULT : out std_logic_vector(LPM_WIDTHP-1 downto 0));
end component;

begin
------------------------COMPONENT INSTANTIATION---------------------------------
        mult1 : LPM_MULT generic map (
                  LPM_WIDTHA => 32,
                  LPM_WIDTHB => 32,
                  LPM_WIDTHP => 64,
                  LPM_REPRESENTATION => "SIGNED",
                  LPM_PIPELINE => 4
        )

--ERROR IS HERE↓

        port map ( DATAA => i_x, DATAB => i_x, CLOCK => i_clk, RESULT => xx );

--ERROR IS HERE↑
```

...

```
        p_mult : process (i_clk, i_rstb)
        begin
```

...

```
        elsif (rising_edge(i_clk)) then
            r_x <= signed(i_x);
            r_y <= signed(i_y);

        o_xx <= std_logic_vector ('0' & xx - yy);
        o_yy <= std_logic_vector (r_X*r_y & '0');

        end if;
        end process p_mult;


end arc;
```

And I am getting two errors at line 49, which is highlighted, saying `type of identifier "xx" does not agree with its usage "std_logic_vector" type` and `cannot associate formal port "RESULT" of mode "out" with an expression`.

I'm not sure what to change for this part, a significant portion of the code is provided in the manual.

How do I fix this?

Comment: try `o_xx <= std_logic_vector(resize(xx-yy), 65);` and `xx` is `signed` but `RESULT` is of type `std_logic_vector` what cannot be directly associated, you need to cast `xx` first.

Comment: @po.pe it's showing the same errors

Comment: @po.pe I'm not sure how to cast it correctly, I changed it to "o_xx <= std_logic_vector(resize(std_logic_vector(xx)-std_logic_vector(yy)), 65);" but it's still giving me the same errors.

Comment: You need to cast it in the `port map`, what's the size of `RESULT`?

Comment: @po.pe It's `RESULT : out std_logic_vector(LPM_WIDTHP-1 downto 0));`, and `LPM_WIDTHP : natural;`, this part of code is provided in the manual.

Comment: But the value of `LPM_WIDTHP` has to be defined somewhere...

Comment: @po.pe It's defined in the code in the question, `LPM_WIDTHP => 64`.

Comment: The first error shows up (with different  types and objects) in 8 questions here on Stackoverflow, the second error in two. Both have answers. If you're going to claim they are related you should provide a [mcve]. Search for error messages first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a helper signal

```
signal result : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);

port map ( 
    DATAA => i_x, 
    DATAB => i_x, 
    CLOCK => i_clk, 
    RESULT => result
);
xx <= signed(result);
```

or maybe they can be cast directly - never tried to be honest - like

```
port map ( 
    DATAA => i_x, 
    DATAB => i_x, 
    CLOCK => i_clk, 
    signed(RESULT) => xx 
);
```

as mentioned [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/356992/177428)

Comment: I tried that, and now the error is `Error (10794): VHDL error at G14lpm.vhd(50): output designator RESULT cannot contain an actual type-conversion`.

Comment: Ah sorry, it's an output... I changed the answer